# Minimum pair of integer sets with distinct sum of pairs

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $A, B$ be two sets of positive integers. Define $A\bigoplus B=\{a+b | a\in A, b\in B\}$ representing all distinct sums of pairs in the Cartesian product of A and B. If all such $m*n$ sums are distinct, we want to know how compact the sets A and B can be. Formally:

Let $f(m, n)=min\{max\{A\bigoplus B\}\}$ for all $A, B\subset Z^+$ with $|A|=m, |B|=n, |A\bigoplus B| = |A| * |B|$. What do we know about $f(m, n)$?

Exact or asymptotic bounds would both help.

I can come up with a trivial bound $f(m, n) = O(2^{m+n})$ since any partition of $\{2^i | 0\leq i \leq m+n-1\}$ satisfies the above conditions. But due to the similarity of this problem with Golumb Ruler and Sidon Sequence, I would conjecture a quadratic bound for m and n.

Answer (score 2):

The bound is exactly $mn+1$: one can take
$$
A = \{1,2,\dots,m\} \quad\text{and}\quad B = \{1,m+1,2m+1,\dots,m(n-1)+1\}
$$
to achieve $mn+1$ for the maximal sum, and we can't do any better because all $mn$ sums are integers greater than or equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you! The result looks surprisingly neat and easy.